# Using JButtons as Tabs

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea, jtabbedpane

Could I use JButtons as tabs? Since the `JTabbedPane` cannot hold the same component in multiple tabs, would there be a way for a JButton to be a tab? I know it looks like tiDE([Website](http://tide.olympe.in/)) uses the JButtons as a tab. How would I do that?

I could make something like this

```
JButton newTab = new JButton("New Tab");
newTab.addActionListener(
  new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        JButton tab = new JButton("Tab 1");
        JToolBar.add(tab) 
        tab.addActionListener(
          new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                makeTextAreaTab();
             }
          } 
       );
     }
  }
);
```

But, how would I make the method `makeTextAreaTab()`? It would have to be the same component as my other editor(JTextArea), and have the same functionality as a JTabbedPane.

Comment: While with Swing you cannot put the same component in multiple containers, you can have different components (JButtons here) use the same basic nucleus (here the button's AbstractAction), so that you are effectively sharing the same JButton across "tabs" on the JTabbedPane.

Comment: Regarding, `"But, how would I make the method makeTextAreaTab()? It would have to be the same component as my other editor(JTextArea), and have the same functionality as a JTabbedPane."` -- please clarify what you are trying to do because based on your text above, I'm sorry, but I have no idea.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I would like to be able to have buttons serve the functionality of tabs. Click on one button, it moves to one editor. Click on another button, it moves to another editor.

Answer (score 0):

You state in a comment:

> I would like to be able to have buttons serve the functionality of tabs. Click on one button, it moves to one editor. Click on another button, it moves to another editor.

Consider using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this where your JButtons (or perhaps better, a JComboBox) tells the CardLayout-using container which "card" (which component -- here a JScrollPane/JTextArea combination) to display.

Comment: OK, the card layout works, but the only problem is that when I edit the JTextArea on one tab, on the other it contains the edits.